# Overlay a gradient shader mask on part of the image

Tags: flutter, dart, shader

I'm using the following code to create a shadermask,

```
  ShaderMask _gradientPng() {
    return ShaderMask(
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('images/profile2.jpg'),
        height: 150,
        width: 100,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
        return LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xFF396AEA), Color(0xFF3B6EEC)],
          stops: [
            0.0,
            0.5,
          ],
        ).createShader(bounds);
      },
      blendMode: BlendMode.overlay,
    );
  }
```

The effect that I'm trying to achieve is as follows,

[image]

Unfortunately, the above code overlays the gradient all over the image. How do I get the desired effect using shader mask? How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your `LinearGradient` better.

I change the ending color to **Colors.transparent**.

But also provide the **begin** and **end** point for the gradient

Try this code.

```
LinearGradient(
  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  end: Alignment.topCenter,
  colors: [Color(0xFF396AEA), Colors.transparent],
  stops: [
    0.0,
    0.7,
  ],
  tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
).createShader(bounds);
```

Play with the **colors** and the **stops** params to adjust the effect.

You can also change **tileMode**. Try `TileMode.mirror` or `TileMode.clamp`

---

To add a border radius to the image wrap your `Image()` widget like this, with a `ClipRRect()`

```
 ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    child: Image(
      image: AssetImage('images/profile2.jpg'),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: is it possible to add a corner radius to the image?

Comment: I added some code to get the radius in the image. Also look at the tileMode for the effect.

Comment: I think the border image radius effect can became a problem with your gradient effect, so use it with caution.